# Opening a specific page on Mac Preview from Terminal

Tags: terminal, preview, iterm

How I can modify the `open filename.pdf` command so that I can open a desired page number directly without having to scroll down.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately the `open` command does not have an *option* to pass to Preview to tell it to go to a given page.  Additionally, Preview does not have an AppleScript Dictionary to make scripting a solution easier, however it's not impossible.  The *bash script* below takes two *arguments*, the *filename* of the document to *open* and the *page number* to *go to*. Note that if the target file to *open* is not in the *working directory* in Terminal then the fully qualified *pathname* must be used.

You'll need to create a file to place this *code* into and make it *executable*. It should be in a *directory* that is in the `$PATH`, otherwise, to use it, you'll have to provide the fully qualified *pathname* to the *executable* or use `./executable` if at the *working directory* of the *executable* in Terminal.

For this example, using the default Terminal, which opens to one's Home Directory:

```
touch OpenToPage
open OpenToPage
```

Now copy and paste the *code*, from the **Code:** section below, into the opened document and save it, then close it.

While still in Terminal, make the file *executable*:

```
chmod u+x OpenToPage
```

To use `OpenToPage`:

```
./opentopage /path/name/to/filename.pdf 3
```

Or:

```
./opentopage '/path/name/to/file name.pdf' 3

./opentopage /path/name/to/file\ name.pdf 3
```

---

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
    [[ -z $1 ]] && printf "\n Missing Filename..."
    printf "\n Missing Page Number...\n\n"
    printf "   Syntax: OpenToPage Filename Page_Number\n"
    printf "   Example: OpenToPage Filename.pdf 3\n\n"
    exit 1
else
    open -a Preview "$1"
    sleep .5
    osascript -e 'tell application "Preview" to activate' \
              -e 'delay 0.25' \
              -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Preview" to click menu item "Go to Page…" of menu "Go" of menu bar 1' \
              -e 'delay 0.25' \
              -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"$2\"" \
              -e 'delay 0.25' \
              -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 36'
fi
exit 0
```

---

Notes: If the target *filename* and or *pathname* has spaces, the spaces must be escaped with a `\` (backslash) or the target *filename* and or *pathname* must be quoted, but not both.

The `sleep` and `delay` times can be adjusted if/as necessary.  As the script is presently written the timings adds 1.25 seconds total to the whole process and should probably be fine as is. If I had to adjust anything I'd change the value of `sleep`, to `.75` or `1`, before modifying the values of `delay`.

The naming of the *bash script* file in this answer is arbitrary, name it whatever you like, e.g. `otp` or `o2p` for *open to page*, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It seems to be working for me, and slightly faster, even with the `sleep` and `delay`s removed.

Comment: I did upvote your post, on 14 October, and then I came back later to add a comment.

Comment: @sjy, Sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks for the upvote! :)