# Terminal open page 5 of PDF in Preview

Tags: terminal, applescript, preview

I am trying to automate the task of using Preview to open a PDF to a certain page number. How can I do this in the terminal or using AppleScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer to this question over [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233945/opening-a-specific-page-on-mac-preview-from-terminal). I have removed some things from that answer but it can be summed up as this.

Create a new bash script (I am going to call it `openpage` - no file extension) somewhere in your `$PATH` with this text:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
    [[ -z $1 ]] && printf "\n Missing the filename."
    printf "\n Missing the page number.\n\n"
    printf "   Syntax: openpage file page_number\n"
    exit 1
else
    open -a Preview "$1"
    sleep .5
    osascript -e 'tell application "Preview" to activate' \
              -e 'delay 0.1' \
              -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Preview" to click menu item "Go to Page…" of menu "Go" of menu bar 1' \
              -e 'delay 0.1' \
              -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"$2\"" \
              -e 'delay 0.1' \
              -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 36'
fi
exit 0
```

Once that is done make sure it is executable with `chmod +x <filename>` and run it like `openpage my_file.pdf 194`